# Конструктор формул (попытка)

Tags: c#

Приветствую. Я начинающий программист на С-шарпе... решил сделать нечто вроде конструктора формул... Вооот: пользователь набирает последовательно свою формулу через кнопки, в коде формируется строка. Внимание, вопрос: как преобразовать правильно эту сроку в обычную формулу для вычислений? У меня это единственная проблема в проекте.

Comment: Действительно, единственная проблема в проекте - это сам проект.
Самое простое - [метод рекурсивного спуска][1].

   [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы строите строку, то есть, теряете информацию. Не стройте строку, стройте дерево разбора сразу.

---
Update: был неправ, не дочитал, что формула вводится _последовательно_. В таком случае — да, у вас отсутствует самая важная часть. Весь проект на самом деле не что иное как обёртка над парсером, а парсера-то вам как раз и не хватает.

Answer (score 2):

Самое первое, что необходимо уяснить в построении формул - это грамматика.  
Грамматика - это набор правил, которые преобразовывают формулу в дерево вычислений.  
Когда вы определитесь с грамматикой - посмотрите в сторону [Sprache](https://github.com/sprache/sprache).Эта библиотека специально создана для построения своих собственных парсеров. Но, так как она использует функциональный подход к программированию, в ней необходимо разбираться достаточно долгое время, однако, на мой взгляд, это более рациональный и быстрый метод, чем метод рекурсивного спуска.

Comment: *Не стоит рыть траншею лопатой, если под рукой есть экскаватор,но и строить собачью конуру из бетонных блоков с помощью крана - не верх инженерной культуры, а признак её отсутствия* (Крис Касперски).

Comment: Благодарю Вас за отличную фразу.=)