# Булевая формула в метод

Tags: c#

Нужно засунуть в метод булевую формулу, чтобы рекурсивно проверять ее истинность. Как это можно реализовать?(Формула задается пользователем)

Comment: А что за булевая формула? Строка с каким-то математическим выражением?

Comment: Видимо нужно писать свое подобие синтаксического анализатора, который будет распознавать формулу с последующей интерпретацией в виде `Func` к примеру. Слишком общий вопрос на мой взгляд.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Конструктор формул (попытка)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/261196/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

Сложность решения задачи зависит от того, известна ли формула заранее или он может быть произвольная:

- Формула известна

  Если формула заранее известна, а пользователь вводит коэффициенты,
  то эти коэффициенты можно вычленить какими-нибудь регулярками и
  подставить в заранее определенный метод.
- Формула неизвестна

Вот тут задача уже не такая простая и в большей степени творческая. Нужно анализировать синтаксис, порядок операторов и т п вещи. Например, преобразовав все в обратную польскую запись для удобства и выполнив действия.